# Retain Marker color on Line History Series in Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on an app, which requires me to highlight few points on History Chart (I am using Highchart's Highstocks).

[Highlighting Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634818/highcharts-changing-color-on-hover-ranking-chart)

this question seems to be answering my question, but my point is this - I cannot add marker & plotoptions only to this graph as in backend I am using python class which renders the data for all history chart. So I prefer this modification to be done in frontend.

One more Question which answers similar requirements is

[Comparing the Marker Points to average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067685/conditional-marker-colors-in-highcharts)

In my application this comparison also is done with respect to the array of elements against list of values. (I can render an array which has same number of elements as of data points, that are to be compared).

While drawing the graph I am getting properly, required points are in required colors. My question goes here

When I hover out of the changed color markers, the color of marker turns to default color. (I may have lost, but need a way to figure out) (1) How can I retain the changed color ? Or (2) Is there a better way to assign colors to marker points rendered the array of values to be compared as stated above ?

I am new to highcharts, any help in this regard is welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to highlight one or more points outside of the initial plot configuration?  The easiest way would be to [update the specific points](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) *after* the plot is initially drawn.

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts()
chart.series[0].points[4].update({color: 'red'});
```

Here's an example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7GqL/).

Comment: Thanks for making out your time & helping me... This answer of yours gave me broad overview, I could able to achieve what I wanted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083794/dynamically-draw-marker-on-last-point-in-highcharts answer in this question may be helpful too along with your answer...